# Permenetly disabling Ethernet connections

Tags: networking, ethernet

Hello there and thank you for dropping in this question.
So I'm trying to permanently disable any type of Ethernet connections to my system(but still keeping WiFi enabled), this means that even if you plug a new different Ethernet card, it still would be denied by the system. It seems like GNOME can easily recognize an Ethernet connection and differ that from WiFi so I hope there is any solution.
Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: Question is why.  Ethernet is more secure than WiFi and faster.  Removing the cable will disable it, and if anyone got your computer they could probably change anything you would do anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out,
I just ended up configuring NetworkManager to ignore all Ethernet connections.
If you want to reproduce it you can just edit this as such:

> /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

and adding this to it

> [main] 
> plugins=keyfile
>
> [keyfile] 
> unmanaged-devices=interface-name:e*;

Do not forget to reload the service afterwards!